# Is mainnet and Homestead the same thing?

Tags: homestead

I understand that `mainnet` is the official public (real-world) Ethereum blockchain that everyone uses to send real Ether to each other.

However, sometimes I see Ethereum being refered to as Homestead. Does the terms refer to the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Mainnet** as you've correctly identified is the public (production) version of the Ethereum blockchain.

Ethereum implementations have had period releases with **Homstead** being the latest release.

The ETHEREUM mainnet and the ETHEREUM nodes that are currently part of the mainnet will be running the Homestead release of the protocol.

Comment: Thank you. I guess you have misspelled something in the third sentence.